# Claims Error? Reference to type 'TokenValidationParameters' claims it is defined in 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt'

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm getting a kind of error I have never seen before in .NET. I'm a little confused as to which way to troubleshoot this one.

I don't understand the "Claims to be defined in" error. Specifically,
Reference to type 'TokenValidationParameters' claims it is defined in 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt' I've used DotNetPeak. TokenValidationParameters is for sure in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
and not in my copy of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.

So what is a "claim"? How does it know? I've just gone through a process of getting about 100 NuGet packages aligned. and this is my last issue. I can't seem to find code that will work here. I'm in .NET 4.8 in an ASP.NET API 5 project.

My code is below

```
using MyApiProject.Shared;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Owin;

namespace MyApiProject
{
    public class AuthConfig
    {
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app, IApiSettings appSettings)
        {
            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters();
            tokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience = appSettings.Get("aad-audience-id");
            tokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";

            var authOptions = new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions();
            authOptions.Tenant = appSettings.Get("aad-tenant-id"); 
            authOptions.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;

            var openIdConnectOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = appSettings.Get("aad-audience-id"),
                Authority = appSettings.Get("aad-authority"),
                RedirectUri = appSettings.Get("aad-redirect-uri") + "/hangfire"
            };
            
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(authOptions);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdConnectOptions);
        }
    }
}
```